# Getting 'An Expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected' error using an IIF statement in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, iif

The IIf statement below is throwing 'An Expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected' error.

How do you return a boolean value using an IIf statement within a WHERE clause in SQL server?  I tried Casting the result to a bit but it didn't work...

```
DELETE FROM Assignments
    WHERE AssignedObjectTypeID=@AssignedObjectTypeID AND AssignedObjectID=@AssignedObjectID 
    AND TargetObjectTypeID=201 AND IIf(@Entity Is Null,1,0)
```

Comment: Why not just `AND @Entity is null`? What is the `Iif` meant to be adding for you? (Which, by the way, you cannot do as you're trying since there are no *boolean literals* in T-SQL)

Comment: where clause filters out results,this IIF clause you have is trying to assign some value

Comment: T-SQL has boolean expressions, but it has no boolean values, and yes, this is one of the many delightful shortcomings of the language. `BIT` is not a boolean type in T-SQL either, though client applications often treat it as such, and it can hold conditional results in a pinch -- but you would still always need to test the value explicitly against `1` or `0`. `AND IIF(@Entity IS NULL, 1, 0) = 1` is legal, but of course unnecessarily verbose, per Damien's remark -- it simplifies to `AND @Entity IS NULL`.

Comment: I had simplified my IIF statement in order to understand the general logic.  It now all makes sense to me, thank you all!